# Upgrade TWS master from 9.3 to 9.5

Tags: db2, websphere, upgrade, websphere-liberty

Need some help on TWS/IWS upgrade from 9.3 to 9.5.
As 9.3 is out of support version , we are not getting help from IBM team. Can some one please help with the procedure to upgrade DB2,WAS liberty , DWC and IWS upgrade.

DB2 is upgraded successfully today. Stuck with Websphere liberty installation.

Thanks in advance

Srinivasa Rao

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is for programming questions. But your question is about administration.

Please refer to the "IBM Workload Automation" v9.5 "Planning and Installation Guide" for upgrading information, taking care to ensure your starting point is only the most recent fixpack for the v9.5 build.

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/workload-automation/9.5.0?topic=installation-upgrading  and all related pages in this category, some studying required, careful planning, rehearse in a non-production environment first.

In general consider upgrading only to the "currently supported" versions of IBM software, if you wish to avail of IBM paid support services.